# Cypher - Issue with Where + Aggregate + With

Tags: cypher

I am trying to execute the following Cypher query

```
START b=node:customer_idx(ID = 'ABCD')   
MATCH p = b-[r1:LIKES]->stuff, someone_else_too-[r2:LIKES]->stuff
with b,someone_else_too, count(*) as matchingstuffcount
where matchingstuffcount > 1
//with   b, someone_else_too, matchingstuffcount, CASE WHEN ...that has r1, r2... END as SortIndex
return someone_else_too, SortIndex
order by SortIndex
```

The above query works fine but moment I uncomment lower "with"  I get following errors

```
Unknown identifier `b`.
Unknown identifier `someone_else_too`.
Unknown identifier `matchingstuffcount`.
Unknown identifier `r1`.
Unknown identifier `r2`.
```

To get around, I include r1 and r2 in the top with - `"with b,someone_else_too, count(*) as matchingstuffcount".`  to `"with b, r1, r2, someone_else_too, count(*) as matchingstuffcount".` This messes my `count(*) > 1` condition as count(*) does not aggregate properly.

Any workarounds / suggestions to filter out count(*) > 1 while making sure Case When can also be executed ?

Answer (score 0):

Under neo4j 2.0 via [console.neo4j.org](http://console.neo4j.org) I was able to get the following query to work. I tried to mimic the constructs you had, namely the `WITH`/`WHERE`/`WITH`/`RETURN` sequence. (If I missed something, please let me know!)

```
START n=node:node_auto_index(name='Neo') 
MATCH n-[r:KNOWS|LOVES*]->m 
WITH n,COUNT(r) AS cnt,m 
WHERE cnt >1 
WITH n, cnt, m,  CASE WHEN m.name?='Cypher'  THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS isCypher 
RETURN n AS Neo, cnt, m, isCypher 
ORDER BY cnt
```

Update it or change it [here](http://console.neo4j.org/r/7nj9).

Comment: Hi Edward, In your solution the problem will come if you wanted to return r (or an attribute of an r). So the query will look like START n=node:node_auto_index(name='Neo') 
MATCH n-[r:KNOWS|LOVES*]->m 
WITH n, r, COUNT(r) AS cnt,m 
WHERE cnt > 1 
WITH n, r, cnt, m,  CASE WHEN m.name?='Cypher'  THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS isCypher 
RETURN n AS Neo, cnt, m, isCypher, r 
ORDER BY cnt. This will return no rows (or wrong count). See here for the simulation [link](http://console.neo4j.org/r/i59lpv)

Comment: But that makes absolute sense because if you add `r` to the first `WITH` clause, you are effectively grouping each relationship separately. That means all rows will fail the `WHERE cnt>1` test. In your example, you get results if you remove the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: So put it simply. I have a relationship attribute Pct. I would like to sort desc by. So I use Order By r.Pct. Also, I want to weed out rows that have count less than 2 as those skew my results. In the example that you have shared, we can do one or the other but not both - and filtering and sorting on relationship is what I am trying to do.